# Has anyone tried to map out all the different Star Trek timelines?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel

I'm thinking of some sort of visual guide to show the relative relationships of all these time-based events.

Comment: [Memory Alpha has a table with all the time travel episodes of each series.](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Time_travel_episodes)

Comment: Down this path lies madness.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out [Information is Beautiful - Timelines: Time travel in popular films and tv](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/timelines/)

There are a lot of other Sci-Fi time travelers listed on there along with the Star Trek crews.

Comment: Right.  Of COURSE David McCandless did this.  Damn is he ever awesome.

Comment: +1 for awesome graphic, though it doesn't include Doctor Who ;-)

Comment: @Jeff: I don't even want to imagine how much more complicated it gets with The Doctor. The timey-wimey-ness makes my brain hurt.

Comment: Downvoted, because although I'm certain that image is gorgeous, I'm also certaint hat it will one day suffer link rot, and there should be some description of what it portrays in the answer itself.

Comment: @Zibbobz I gave as much description as I felt was necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Fair enough.  It does only ask if such an image exists, and not for a description of it nor an explanation.

Comment: @Zibbobz FWIW, I'm kind of torn about just linking to the graphic. Normally I'd put it inline along with the link, but that image is 100% of the post on a site that makes their living producing these kinds of graphics. I don't want to steal views from them, or I'm certain their site *will* have to be taken down. (I don't mind the downvote, just trying to clarify/justify my thinking.)

Comment: I don't see Babylon 5 on there either - B4's trip from 2258 to the mid-1200's (appx. 1000 years).